# Zend view helper & partialLoop : rendering order

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, partials, view-helpers

I have a view helper that use a partialLoop.

Easy, but i want my view helper to return the content of the partialLoop inside an Html tag. So the helper would have the responsability of the html tag surrounding the generated content.

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract{

private function myFactory($data) {

    $html .= '<table id="myTable"><tr>';
    $html .= $this->view->partialLoop('_partials/_item.phtml', $data);
    $html .= '</tr></table>';
    return $html;
}

public function myHelper($data) {
    return $this->myFactory($data);

}

}
```

When i use this code, the table and tr html tags are all rendered after the partialLoop, which is not the behavior that i want.

Comment: Please post your _item.phtml. Maybe its just a tr/td rendering problem.

Comment: You were true, tr/td rendering problem... I missed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was a tr/td rendering problem.